# onclick of td change td css

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

```
<div id="divScroll" style="overflow-x: hidden">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelTableAppointment" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate> <table border="1" id="myTable">
    <tr class="csstr">
    <td class="csstdgreen" rowspan="3">
        john
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</asp:UpdatePanel>  </div>
```

Above is my html i have to check in jquery onclick of table td if td has class csstdgreen and rowspan is not null
then i have to make that  td having csstdgreen and having rowspan 1,2,3 etc then make it yellow.

How can i achieve with jquery

```
 $('#myTable td').click(function ()
                    {
                        if ($('td').hasClass("csstdgreen") && $('td').attr('rowspan'))
                        {
                            alert("Hi");
                            $('.csstdgreen').removeClass('csstdselected');
                            $('td').removeClass('csstdgreen').addClass('csstdselected');
                        }

                    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the reference `this` to make changes to the targeted `td`:

```
$('#myTable td').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("csstdgreen") && $(this).attr('rowspan') )
    {
        alert("Hi");
        $('.csstdgreen').removeClass('csstdselected');
        $(this).removeClass('csstdgreen').addClass('csstdselected');
    }
});​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KbR4c/)

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? Is it simply not generating the alert? Is your console logging a specific error? You likely haven't included jQuery correctly. Also know that this has to be executed on dom ready http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Open the browser's error console (I think it's F12) and see if it reports an error.

Comment: @John You don't have a closing tag for your `ContentTemplate` -- working demo with your updated html http://jsfiddle.net/pwwCw/

Comment: nbrooks But when <td class="csstdgreen" rowspan="1"> above code is not working why

Comment: [`.live()` is deprecated](http://liveisdeprecated.com) -- Use `.on()`. Also, my demo works when I use rowspan 1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14262/discussion-between-nbrooks-and-john)

Comment: $('#contentPlaceHolderMain_tableAppointment td').live('click', function (e)
    {
     if ($(this).hasClass("csstdgreen") && $(this).attr('rowspan'))
     {
      $(".csstdselected").removeClass("csstdselected").addClass('csstdgreen');
      $(this).removeClass('csstdgreen').addClass('csstdselected');      
     }
    });